# A simple group with $|\operatorname{Syl}_p⁡ G| \le 6$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a simple, finite group, s.t. for every prime $p$, it satisfies $k_p=\left|\operatorname{Syl}_p⁡ G\right| \le 6$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

**My attempt:** Let $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\ldots p_r^{e_r}$ be the (distinct) prime factorization of $n = \left|G\right|$. If $n$ is prime, $G$ is cyclic. So we assume $e_1\ge 1$ and $e_2\ge1$. From Sylow's theorems, we have $k_{p_1}\mid\prod_{i\ne1} p_i^{e_i}$ and $k_{p_1}\equiv1\ (\operatorname{mod} p_1)$, and the same applies for $p_2$. Sicne $G$ is simple, $k_{p_{1,2}}\ne1$, and it is given that $k_{p_{1,2}}\le6$. The options for $p_1$ are

1. No prime $p_1$ satisfies $k_{p_1}=2$.
2. The other options are that $p_1=2,3,5$ and $k_{p_1}=3,4,6$ respectively.

How do I continue from here?

Comment: $4$ is not prime, so you cannot have $p_1=4$. Also $k_p = 1,2,3,4$ are impossible in a nonabelian simple group, so you are left with $k_2=5$ and $k_5=6$ to think about. Then $k_2=5 \Rightarrow G \le A_5$, so $|G|$ divides $20$.

Comment: @DerekHolt changed, thank you. Why does $k_2=5$ implies that $G\le A_5$?

Comment: The conjugation action of $G$ on the set of Sylow $5$-subgroups induces and embedding $G \to S_5$ but then $G$ simple implies that it embeds into $A_5$.

Comment: Roy, if you completed this exercise following Derek Holt's hint, feel free to post your solution as an answer. That way you get more feedback on the details.

Comment: Actually $k_5\neq 6$ since $3$ cannot divide $|G|$. This maybe is easier than embedding in $A_5$.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, let's assume that $G$ is nonabelian simple group, which implies that $60=|A_5|\le |G|$. As you mentioned, for any prime $p\in \pi(G)$, $k_p \equiv 1  \pmod{p}$. Since $G$ is nonabelian simple group $k_p> 1$, for every $p\in \pi(G)$, hence $p<k_p\le 6$, which implies $\pi(G)\subseteq\{2,3,5\}$. On the other hand, by Burnside's $p^\alpha q^\beta$-theorem, we get that $\pi(G)=\{2,3,5\}$. Now we see that $k_3=4$, which is a contradiction, because that way $G\le S_4$ (actually $G\le A_4$, since $G$ is assumed to be a simple group).

Comment: You don't need Buirnside's $p^\alpha q^\beta$-theorem to prove this. As I pointed out in my comment, you can quickly deduce $G \le A_5$, and then it is easy.